# Theory questions about training the model in terms of optimization

Tags: python, optimization, neural-network, training-data, graph-neural-network

can you please explain, how training the graph neural network or CNN works? in case I have graphs and I choose batch_size = 16 this means, each graph may have a different number of nodes and edges.

**Q1**

> The epochs parameter specifies the number of times the entire training
> dataset will be processed by the model during training. so how's this
> working if I set epochs = 30  and the batch_size=16? what effect do
> epochs have other than if I want to train the model more?

**Q2**

```
            opt.zero_grad()
            output = model(graphs) # imgs
            
            loss.backward()
            opt.step()
```

> I guess the previous code is useful to update the model's parameters to minimize
> the error between the predictions and the actual outputs.
>
> can you please explain how the process of the following
> code works?
> and why is it in terms of optimization, that if we get a
> low value of loss we make a small step toward the correct solution and
> if the loss is high then we make a big step?

**Q3**

> when we face the phenomenon that the optimization is not moving and
> what causes optimization to not be moving? it's always the case when
> the loss value is 0.70, 0.60, 0.70

**Q4**

> What could be the remedies in case the loss function/learning curve is
> not converging?  some say (increase the number of epochs as train
> more) or (decrease the learning rate) some say increase the
> batch_size, why?

```
def train(train_loader, epochs, criterion, writer, model, optimizer):

    # train
    for epoch in range(1, epochs + 1):
        total_loss = 0
        model.train()
        for batch in train_loader:
            for data in batch:  
                data.cuda()
                opt.zero_grad()
                output = model(imgs)
                loss = criterion(output, y)
                loss.backward()
                opt.step()
                total_loss += loss
            print("Epoch {}. Loss: {:.4f}".format(
                epoch, total_loss))
    return model
```

Answer (score 0):

**Q1**: You would divide the total number of training samples by the batch size. This gives you the number of parameter update steps per epoch.
**Q2**: I suggest you look up the basics of back-propagation and stochastic gradient descent. The basic idea is to run a forward pass for calculating the error between the labels and the model predictions measured with a loss function. This value is then used to update the weights using a method called back-propagation.
**Q3/Q4**: There can be many reasons for non-convergence. For example, it could be programming bugs or issues with the applied method (data pre-processing, model architecture, etc.) or far from optimal hyper-parameters (the learning rate is one of the more important ones), or many other problems. I would start by overfitting the model on a couple of samples so that you can iterate quickly. If that works and you have gained some confidence in your implementation, you can dive deeper into hyper-parameter optimization and other paths for improvement. In general, I'd suggest to look up a guide on how to debug machine learning code, there are good resources online already.